# What is causing my write to registry to crash with an error message of "Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service."

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, windows-7, registry

I have made some changes to my application that will allow the application to continue to function in Windows 7.  Previously, the application would set and get from `Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE", True)` but, with the advent of Windows 7 that must change.  According to Microsoft, ""

Dim key As RegistryKey ' Is a Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey which is pointing at Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE", True)))

My registry key is built from:
`ExecutionArgs.ApplicationKey(Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE", True))`

My variables are:

```
key.Name = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MyApplication\Application Parameters"
key.SubKeyCount = 0
key.ValueCount = 5

Dim byts() As Byte ' This byte array has {Length=1965879}

key.SetValue("Constants", byts) '
```

This dies with error message

```
"Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service."
```

I am including data which appears pertinent to me, if more is necessary please advise.

Has anyone come up against this an been able to overcome it?

Comment: You really shouldn't be putting almost 2MB worth of data into the registry. And it sounds like Microsoft agrees.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly, I inherited this and am trying to band aid fix it until I have time to gut the existing reg entries and store in a memorystream or some similar structure.  My issue is, this works when storing to the LocalMachine but not when storing to the CurrentUser.

Comment: Fair enough, sorry for the flip remark. Not really sure how you can overcome it, though if you're going to be updating code already, you might just want to bite the bullet and write code to store and retrieve the data in a more sensible place. Another option would be to break up the data and store it in more than one Value (e.g. Constants1, Constant2, etc.)

Comment: I was starting that process.  I decided to take a break and pick the brains of the community before I get too far down the hole.  Thanks for your opinion and response.  It's always good to know that your opinion is shared by someone else. Helps justify the time and expense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the root cause and solution to my problem is that in Windows 7 a WPF application cannot be run as an administrator directly.

I have subsequently Changed from storing my data in the registry to storing it in a memorystream.

Comment: This is not limited to WPF applications a not to Windows 7. This comes from the UAC feature build in from Windows Vista. It can be disabled but even then non administrator users can't write that local machine registry key. Not even on older Windows version. The current user registry key is always writable by the current user, even if not an admin. This is not different for a WPF application.

Comment: I did not say it was limited to Windows 7, but it is an issue for me in Windows 7. No, the current user is not writable from a WPF application.  I have tried this extensively and it will not work.